# Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content and Unexpected token , in my json

Tags: json, json.net

I am having some problems with my json-feed created with JSON.Net. 
When I try to parse it, it gives me

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,.
>   Path '', line 17, position 4.

I tried validating it with http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,".

Any ideas why ?

I have pasted my json below:

```
{
    "ReviewId": 10250,
    "DateOfVisit": "Wed, 04 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +01:00",
    "SmartDateOfVisit": "Wednesday, January 04, 2012 12:00 AM",
    "First": null,
    "IsFeatured": null,
    "Rating": 5,
    "Text": "nice food",
    "ReviewTitle": "superb experience",
    "DisplayName": "mr. X",
    "ProfilePagePath": "http://facebook.com",
    "ProfileImage": "http://facebook.com/images/anonymous.png",
    "UserReviewsWritten": 119,
    "PlaceName": "Some place",
    "PlaceUrl": "http://www.somesite.com/someplace"
  },
{
    "ReviewId": 10250,
    "DateOfVisit": "Wed, 04 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +01:00",
    "SmartDateOfVisit": "Wednesday, January 04, 2012 12:00 AM",
    "First": null,
    "IsFeatured": null,
    "Rating": 5,
    "Text": "nice food",
    "ReviewTitle": "superb experience",
    "DisplayName": "mr. X",
    "ProfilePagePath": "http://facebook.com",
    "ProfileImage": "http://facebook.com/images/anonymous.png",
    "UserReviewsWritten": 119,
    "PlaceName": "Some place",
    "PlaceUrl": "http://www.somesite.com/someplace"
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{ ... }` is valid JSON. After that, `,` is an unexpected token. After that, `{ ... }` is trailing garbage.